# SQL Server 2014: create procedure with cursor output parameter

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, database-cursor

I am new to this stored procedures my question is related to cursor output parameter. what is the difference between cursor output parameter and a normal stored procedure like it just a variable or it effect the result or performance of query?

I am using SQL Server 2014. Creating a stored procedure I used the shortcut key alt+k, alt+x. in the list I have selected stored procedure after selecting the stored procedure, it ask to choose stored procedure type:

1. Create procedure basic template
2. Create procedure with cursor output parameter
3. Create procedure with output parameter.

I couldn't understand the 2nd stored procedure type. I tried to google but didn't get sufficient information. Anyone here to help me to understand will much appreciated. I have attached the 2nd stored procedure type sample script

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Sample_Procedure 
    @sample_procedure_cursor CURSOR VARYING OUTPUT
AS
    SET @sample_procedure_cursor = CURSOR FOR
        select 1
    OPEN @sample_procedure_cursor 
RETURN 0
```

I just want to understand is there any other output I can't see using "cursor varying output" keywords instead of using "@variable datatype;"

Comment: Why do you need this? I did not heard of cursor output parameters. But you can create a procedure that has a cursor inside...

Comment: Use ALT+S, And ALT+X in sql server query window then select Stored procedure among the list. then you will see these three type. I am trying to understand clear my SP Concept. Till before I see this I felt like I Getting know SP very well but this make me curious.

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks I leant a new thing. Let me check if I can understand documentation

Comment: Why are you trying to return a cursor at all? You *don't* need to return a cursor to return results.

Comment: It is just for refactoring code and make it more modular I guess. So you have a definition of a cursor used for a specific area. All other developers can use the same cursor using the SP returning the cursor... I am not a fan this feature, I am just trying to understand the reason behind this question

Comment: @DeepakKavin, although this may be a good learning exercise, be aware that cursor parameters are rarely used in SQL Server in practice. I often see those in T-SQL code migrated from other DBMS products which require cursors to retrieve results. SQL Server natively streams rows to the client without the need for a server-side cursor. It's generally best to use set-based processing and avoid cursors.

Answer (score 1):

Deepak please refer to documentation samples at [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(CREATE_PROCEDURE_TSQL);k(sql13.swb.tsqlresults.f1);k(sql13.swb.tsqlquery.f1);k(MiscellaneousFilesProject);k(DevLang-TSQL)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=sql-server-2017)

If you are using the same cursor repeatedly in your SQL codes you can wrap the definition of the cursor into a SP once and refer to it later.

I copy below the sample code

First create the procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspCurrencyCursor   
    @CurrencyCursor CURSOR VARYING OUTPUT  
AS  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  
    SET @CurrencyCursor = CURSOR  
    FORWARD_ONLY STATIC FOR  
      SELECT CurrencyCode, Name  
      FROM Sales.Currency;  
    OPEN @CurrencyCursor;  
GO
```

Then use it as follows

```
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR;  
EXEC dbo.uspCurrencyCursor @CurrencyCursor = @MyCursor OUTPUT;  
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)  
BEGIN;  
     FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor;  
END;  
CLOSE @MyCursor;  
DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;  
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

A cursor as output is meant to encapsulate the definition of the cursor. This means that you execute an SP to retrieve a cursor that has already been initialized and is linked to a result set which is unknown to the caller, but the caller will use.

This opens up a potential problem in that the caller will need to know which variables to cast the fetching row into and might potentially break the usage of the cursor if done incorrectly. This wouldn't happen if the SP returned a result set with a `SELECT` or inserts into a temporary table created outside, for example.

In my opinion, there is little to none useful applications of this. To start with it's on very rare occasions that you want to use a cursor *at all* and they are usually with operations that don't involve DML and involve system operations, like creating files or sending emails. And even in those cases, hiding the result set from the caller seems pretty obscure.